# Cursor keys do not jump over tabs in Vim

Tags: vim, editors

When I step over a tab with the cursor keys (<kbd>h</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd>), the cursor does not jump over the tab, it just goes one space at a time. This is annoying because I am not sure if there is a tab there or spaces. What I expect is that if I move onto a tab the cursor should situate at the beginning of the tab (the leftmost position) and if I move one space to the right, it should jump to the first character after the tab.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Note that I am using `visualedit=all`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean `virtualedit` instead of `visualedit` (which does not exist)?

You need to disable `virtualedit` in normal mode, as this option defines the handling of tabs for the possible cursor positions; Instead of `all`, use all other values together:

`:set virtualedit=insert,block,onemore`

From `vim` documentation, `:help 'virtualedit'`:

```
'virtualedit' 've'  string  (default "")
    A comma separated list of these words:
        block   Allow virtual editing in Visual block mode.
        insert  Allow virtual editing in Insert mode.
        all     Allow virtual editing in all modes.
        onemore Allow the cursor to move just past the end of the line

    Virtual editing means that the cursor can be positioned where there is
    no actual character.  This can be halfway into a tab or beyond the end
    of the line.  Useful for selecting a rectangle in Visual mode and
    editing a table.
```

From this description, it seems to be not possible to have `virtualedit=all`, except the jump-over-tabs part.

A possible way to implement that is remapping the keys `h` and `l` to jump over tabs explicitly in normal mode, and keep `virtualedit=all`.

Comment: Right, but there is a difference between positioning the cursor where there is no text and positioning in the middle of a tab. Ideally I would like to be able to move the cursor past the end of the line (for editing tables and comments) but still have the cursor respect existing tabs. Not going to happen?

Comment: I agree that makes sense to have, but from the help for 'virtualedit', seems like no, not possible.

Comment: What about remapping the keys `h` and `l` to jump over tabs explicitly in normal mode?